# fetch size for NamedParameterJdbctemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

I am working on a problem which involves me to write a query to fetch few thousands of records from the database. The query which I would be using will include 2 IN clauses in the WHERE condition.

As per my knowledge which might be limited, please feel to correct me, for this use case I cannot use jdbctemplate. I would have to move towards NamedParameterJdbcTemplate since NamedParameterJdbcTemplate gives us the flexibility to use IN clause.

Now my questions which I am looking answers for are as follows.

Q.> NamedParameterJdbcTemplate does not have a setFetchSize method. Is there a way to set the fetch size for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ?

Q> Does anyone has any idea about the default fetch size for the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ? for JdbcTemplate it is set to 10. I know. What about NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ?

Q> even if i use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate my problem would not be resolved, since if we assume that the fetch size of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate would also be 10, fetching few thousand records would still take a lot of my application time.

Can anyone suggest a solution or guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` delegates to a plain `JdbcTemplate` for all JDBC work. So, you can create your `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` passing in a customized `JdbcTemplate` in the constructor. If you customize the `fetchSize` on the `JdbcTemplate` you pass in, then that is what the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` will use as well. See - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#NamedParameterJdbcTemplate-org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations-

Comment: so simplified, that would look like
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        template.getJdbcTemplate().setFetchSize(50);
?